# Templates for character badges for a larp

Tags: larp, prop-construction

I'm getting ready to run a LARP event at a convention and I want to make badges for people to wear with their character's picture and name so that other people can tell which character they are.  How can I best do this, given that I don't have much experience with photo editing software, but do have an interest in learning to use some, if it would be helpful?

Answer (score 3):

Having gamemasterd Vampire LARPS for a decade, here is my take on the badge subject:

- Don't make a picture of the characters. The player's **face** plus makeup and props should be enough to give the character a picture. In a LARP, the player IS the character. If you can take a picture of every player and print them on spot, this could be nice (even for a LARP who-is-who book later) but would defeat the very purpose of id'ing the character (hey, Larry, your character looks like Larry).
- Instead, make a set of easily recognizable icons that can tell other people what that character **is**, and leave the face of the player do the rest.

You can put icons for almost every public recognizable feature:

> Class, Race, Rank, Faction, Alignment...

So, I don't know if you are running a vampire LARP (probably not) but in one I'd use:

- Public Rank (prince, council, ancillae, anarch, etc) of the char. (Sabbath would have the rank of their disguise).
- Clan (tremere, ventrue, etc).
- Elderly status (generation, but we bunched up childe, neophyte, member, knight and elder)
- Any other affiliation (sherrif, conclave, justicar, etc).

So a sample character:

> **Julius Kingsmith, toreador elder**
>
> Badges: council, elder, toreador, sheriff

On a handout we sent every player before the LARP, all those icons were listed, and we instructed players to memorize them.

It helped a lot to let people remember and react properly to someone they had not yet interacted with but the characters should know who it was anyway. Also worked the other way, as Julius could just scoff at neophites (the player knew the neophite badge, and reacted accordingly).